# I want to open an XML file using a relative path in my project using java ee

Tags: xml, servlets, jakarta-ee

In my project Java EE

[image]

[image]

```
String source=getServletContext().getInitParameter("source");
        source=getServletContext().getContextPath()+source;
    //  source=getServletContext().getRealPath(source);
         System.out.println(source);


    RDVDao dao=new RDVDaoXML(source);
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question and don't use screenshots to convey the problem, otherwise the question may be closed.

Comment: okey, i want to read and write from a File XMl my project is developped using java EE so i will use a relative path to access into file XML